# Excel to Text-editor Copying Time-saving method

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, text-editors, text-editing

I have an excel file with **multiple columns and rows**.

I wish to copy the contents of this excel file **column-wise** to a word file.

As the number of **rows and columns are more than 100**, I find it **time-consuming** to do it manually. Is there any method to achieve the same?

Tried using MS PowerAutomate. As a novice, I could not succeed in it.

Images of working Excel file and text/word file is attached.

[image: Excel File]

[image: Word File]

Regards
Anil

Answer (score 0):

Here is how:

- Select the tabular area containing the data
- Right-click it and select "Define Name"
- Give the area a name, say `MyData`
- Click in another cell, say E1, and enter the following formula:

  ```
  =INDEX(MyData, MOD(ROW(A1)-1+COLUMNS(MyData),COLUMNS(MyData))+1, 1+INT((ROW(A1)-1)/COLUMNS(MyData)))
  ```
- Click to select E1 and drag the bottom-right corner down
  over the column E.

Result:

[image]

Comment: @harrync Tried to plug in the formula. Could not succeed in it. If the number of rows and columns are NOT equal, then, I  could not get the desired result. Nevertheless, works perfectly with the given (3*3  example) dataset

Comment: Do you mean that there are blank cells? What is the result?

Comment: Could get the "#REF!" for all the cells after dragging

Comment: I don't know how to do that while skipping blank cells. Very complex mathematics.